# Failing to install ELK

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to install ELK but I am getting below timed out error.

[image]

Comment: Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at localhost:9200. Have you started your ES server?

Comment: Yes. It will run for sometime and  it stops.

Comment: Please post your elasticsearch log. Why is your ES failing to run ?

Answer (score 0):

- Check your log, It might be the situation that your computer's configuration is not good enough to run elk.[elasticsearch can take 1.2g memory].

> use `free -m` `df -h` check the machine can support elk service.
>
> In centos, logs locate on /var/log/elasticsearch.

- You can check your connection with `curl localhost:9200`.
- If your elasticsearch deploys in other machines, you should set the configuration as host: 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Update elasticsearch configuration

- Add below code to **elastcisearch.yml**

  ```
  # vi /etc/elasticsearch/elastcisearch.yml

     network.host: 0.0.0.0
  ```
- If you have enabled authentication for Elasticsearch, update **Logstash** configuration file and provide **user** and **password**.

  ```
  # vi /home/checkstyle.conf 
     output {
          elasticsearch {
               hosts => ['localhost:9200']
               user => 'admin'
               password => 'admin'
               sniffing => true
               manage_template => false
               index => "autocheckstylelogsyncfilebeat"
          }
     }
  ```
- Verify Elasticsearch is active

  ```
  # curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
  ```

  If authentication is enabled

  ```
  # curl -XGET '<user>:<pwd>@localhost:9200'
  ```